# Purge disks after removing Ceph

Tags: centos, ceph

I'm trying to remove ceph totally from my servers. I released OSDs from server node and format disks, create new partition with parted but still see ceph partition inside disks. Followed this procedure to remove OSDs: https://docs.ceph.com/en/nautilus/rados/operations/add-or-rm-osds/#removing-osds-manual

I need to release disks and let Centos use them by itself.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the actual ceph version (Luminous or newer) you should be able to wipe the OSDs with `ceph-volume lvm zap --destroy /path/to/disk` or use the LV syntax: `ceph-volume lvm zap --destroy VG/LV`. This should let you re-use the disks for a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In newer ceph versions which are installed with `cephadm` you can also use

```
ceph orch device zap  my-ceph-host-1 /dev/sdb --force
```

If you don't have ceph clent installed you need to install `ceph-common` and `cephadm` packages.

You can also run commands below but **not recommended**

```
lsblk
sudo lvdisplay
sudo lvremove /dev/ceph-xyz
```